# v-combobox can't listed the items

Tags: vuetify.js

Currently have 2 v-combobox within this vue component, but one is working properly but the second one doesn't. Here's the code,

CreateProd.vue:

```
<Template>
  <v-app> 
  <v-row>
     <v-col cols="6">
       <v-combobox :items="items"></v-combobox>
     </v-col>
  </v-row>
  <v-row>
     <v-col cols="6">
       <v-combobox :operatingSystem="operatingSystem"></v-combobox>
     </v-col>
  </v-row>
  </v-app>
</Template>

<script> 
  export default {
     data() {
       return { 
            items: [
                    'Mobiles & Tablets > Smartphones',
                    'Mobiles & Tablets > Tablets',
                    'Mobiles & Tablets > Landline Phones',
                    'Mobiles & Tablets > Feature Phones'
                   ],
            operatingSystem: [
                              'Windows',
                              'Linux',
                              'Windows XP Professional'
                             ],
       }
     },
   }
</script>
```

The problem is when I click the second combobox, it won't list down the items that created inside the operatingSystems. Plz Help, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used the wrong props in your second Combobox. It should be **:items** and not **:operatingSystem**.

```
WRONG
<v-combobox :operatingSystem="operatingSystem"></v-combobox>
```

```
RIGHT
<v-combobox :items="operatingSystem"></v-combobox>
```